# How to make JFileChooser show every type of files except .huff files

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, filefilter

I'm working on a Java (Swing) program implementing Huffman algorithm. It takes a file and compresses it to filename.huff
I have to make the JFileChooser show every file in the system but not the ones I have compressed that have .huff extension

I haven't tried any code because I don't know how can I do that. But I know how to make a FileFilter that shows only specific type of Files:

```
FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Huffman File","huff");
JFileChooser j = new JFileChooser(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
j.setFileFilter(filter);
int returnVal = j.showOpenDialog(null);
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   txtBrowse.setText(j.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
}
```

So, the question is how to make FileFilter displays all type of files except .huff files?

Comment: You set your FolNameExtension filter to accept all extensions, and in your filter code, you filter out the compressed files.

Comment: That's my point. I can make a filter that shows only .huff files but I don't know how to make a filter that shows every type of files except .huff :\

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter.html) which:

> ..is an abstract class used by JFileChooser for filtering the set of files shown to the user. See `FileNameExtensionFilter` for an implementation that filters using the file name extension.
> A `FileFilter` can be set on a `JFileChooser` to keep unwanted files from appearing in the directory listing. For an example implementation of a simple file filter, see **`yourJDK/demo/jfc/FileChooserDemo/ExampleFileFilter.java`**. For more information and examples see How to Use File Choosers, a section in The Java Tutorial.

Note the bold part which was obtained after a few moments glancing at the [methods of `JFileChooser`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#method.summary) This is something you should do before asking questions on SO.

Here is the effect of implementing one using `.txt` as the file to exclude:

[image]